# How to make my widget clickable?

Tags: android, widget, clickable

My widget is just a battery monitor.
But i want to open a full screen activity with more info.

here is the AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.java:

```
package cogiloo.widget;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        updateWidget(context);
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyBatteryReceiver.class));     

    }

    public void updateWidget(Context context){
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.androidbatterywidget_layout);
        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.level, "waiting!");

        ComponentName myComponentName = new ComponentName(context, AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myComponentName, updateViews);
    }

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Here Battery.java (The Activity i want to open by clicking on my widget):

```
package cogiloo.widget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Battery extends Activity {

    private TextView batteryLevel, batteryVoltage, batteryTemperature, 
                batteryTechnology, batteryStatus, batteryHealth;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        batteryLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterylevel);
        batteryVoltage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batteryvoltage);
        batteryTemperature = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterytemperature);
        batteryTechnology = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterytechology);
        batteryStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterystatus);
        batteryHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batteryhealth);

        this.registerReceiver(this.myBatteryReceiver, 
                new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver myBatteryReceiver 
    = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)){
                batteryLevel.setText("Level: "
                        + String.valueOf(arg1.getIntExtra("level", 0)) + "%");
                batteryVoltage.setText("Voltage: "
                        + String.valueOf((float)arg1.getIntExtra("voltage", 0)/1000) + "V");
                batteryTemperature.setText("Temperature: "
                        + String.valueOf((float)arg1.getIntExtra("temperature", 0)/10) + "c");
                batteryTechnology.setText("Technology: " + arg1.getStringExtra("technology"));

                int status = arg1.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);
                String strStatus;
                if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){
                    strStatus = "Charging";
                } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING){
                    strStatus = "Dis-charging";
                } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){
                    strStatus = "Not charging";
                } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){
                    strStatus = "Full";
                } else {
                    strStatus = "Unknown";
                }
                batteryStatus.setText("Status: " + strStatus);

                int health = arg1.getIntExtra("health", BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN);
                String strHealth;
                if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD){
                    strHealth = "Good";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT){
                    strHealth = "Over Heat";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD){
                    strHealth = "Dead";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE){
                    strHealth = "Over Voltage";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE){
                    strHealth = "Unspecified Failure";
                } else{
                    strHealth = "Unknown";
                }
                batteryHealth.setText("Health: " + strHealth);

            }
        }

    };
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Here my BatteryReceiver:

```
package cogiloo.widget;

import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyBatteryReceiver extends Service {

    private int batterylevel = 0;
    private String batteryStatus ="";

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
            {
                batterylevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);

                int status = intent.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);
                String strStatus;
                if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){
                    batteryStatus = "Charging"; 
                } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING){
                    batteryStatus = "Dis-charging";
                } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){
                    batteryStatus = "Not charging";
                } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){
                    batteryStatus = "Full";
                } else {
                    batteryStatus = "";
                }

                updateAppWidget(context);
            }
        }

        public void updateAppWidget(Context context){
            RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.androidbatterywidget_layout);
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.level, 
                    "Cogiloo Battery\n\n" +
                    "Bat. Status:\n" +
                    "Level: " + batterylevel + "%\n" +
                    "Status: " + batteryStatus);

            ComponentName myComponentName = new ComponentName(context, AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            manager.updateAppWidget(myComponentName, updateViews);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);



    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }



    //borrar esto y el activity Battery y en el maniffest


    public void onClick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Battery.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

//hasta aqui



}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The widget works well, but i couldn´t find any way to make is clickable!

Answer (score 5):

Modify `updateWidget()` to create and assign a new `PendingIntent`.

```
public void updateWidget(Context context){
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.androidbatterywidget_layout);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Battery.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ok Before

```
 manager.updateAppWidget(myComponentName, updateViews);
```

you have to define an intent that is  triggered when you click for example an imagen in your Widget (R.id.imagetoClick)

```
Intent defineIntent = new Intent(); 
    defineIntent.setClassName("cogiloo.widget","cogiloo.widget.ActivitytoShow");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
0 /* no requestCode */, defineIntent, 0 /* no flags */);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagetoClick, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a Widget clickable you need to call `setOnClickPendingIntent` on the widget's Remote View, passing in the resource identifier of the View you want to make clickable, and the Pending Intent you want it to fire.

In your example it would look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Battery.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.level, pi);
```